# Select xarray dataset based on month

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, python-xarray

I have xarray dataset with following info:

```
Coordinates:
lat: float64 (192)
lon: float64 (288)
time: object (1200) (monthly data)

Data Variables:
tas: (time, lat, lon)
```

Now I want values of tas for specific month, for example I want new dataset with all records of month January.

Output dataset will look like this:

```
Coordinates:
lat: float64 (192)
lon: float64 (288)
time: object (100) (monthly data of January)

Data Variables:
tas: (time, lat, lon)
```

I tried a way like this which I used before:

```
jan = pd.date_range(start='1979-01-01', periods=41, freq='AS-JAN').date.tolist()
gs_jan = gs.sel(time = jan)
```

But this won't work in my case cause dates for me is in 0001-0100 year, and pandas doesn't support date in that range!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC I have provided the code of what I tried, I should put example of my xarray dataset?

Comment: You should share a [mcve], which would probably include some data, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally for analysing time-series data like this, you want to follow the group-split-apply approach using xarray's `da.groupby()` method (http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/groupby.html).

In your case, I'd suggest trying:

```
# Use .groupby('time.month') to organize the data into months
# then use .groups to extract the indices for each month
month_idxs=gs.groupby('time.month').groups

# Extract the time indices corresponding to all the Januarys 
jan_idxs=month_idxs[1]

# Extract the january months by selecting 
# the relevant indices
gs_jan=gs.isel(time=jan_idxs)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It work perfectly! Thank you so much. bdw what's the use of month_idxs(1st line of code!) here?

Comment: Ooops! The next line was meant to be `jan_idxs=month_idxs[1]`, but I forgot. haha. Will edit :) Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this with less code is with

[xarray.where()](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v2022.03.0/generated/xarray.where.html?highlight=where)

```
Jan = data.where(((data['time.year'] == 2020) & (data['time.month'] == 1)), drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although [the answer by Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60793478/19380043) already resolved the question, it can be done more directly if you only wish to extract one specific month as

```
gs.groupby('time.month')[1]
```

Here, 1 refers to January. It is more like a dictionary, so simply using the key (actually the label in `groupby` object) can retrieve one specific month and no need to retrieve the index at first.